# C++ - Failing to parse CSV into my struct

Tags: c++, csv, parsing, struct

I have a CSV with the following format:

```
date,fruit,quantity1,quantity2,quantity3
2016-07-14,banana,3,20,6
2016-07-14,banana,3,50,15
2016-07-14,banana,0,25,15
2016-07-14,banana,3,25,6
2016-07-14,apple,3,10,20.5
2016-07-14,apple,0,30,5
2016-07-14,apple,0,5,30
2016-07-14,peach,3,10,30.2
2016-07-14,peach,3,40,4
2016-07-14,peach,3,10,12
2016-07-14,peach,0,10,8
2016-07-14,peach,3,200,3
```

I want to parse this file and store it in a struct.  But I am getting a stack overflow error.  Where is it failing exactly?  Is it because of clashing data types in the struct?  Some of the data types are a float and I'm trying to use getline and a temporary string variable to store the info.

Here is the complete code:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

struct FruitInventory
{
    string date;
    string fruit;
    float quantity1;
    float quantity2;
    float quantity3;
};

int main()
{
    ifstream myfile;
    myfile.open("fruit_inventory.csv", ios::in);

    string line;

    FruitInventory todaysFruitSupply[15000];

    int i = 0;

    int lineCount = 0;

    while (myfile.good())
    {
        getline(myfile, line);

        stringstream mystream(line);

        string temp;

        if (i > 0) //ignore header line
        {
            getline(mystream, todaysFruitSupply[i].date, ',');
            getline(mystream, todaysFruitSupply[i].fruit, ',');
            getline(mystream, temp, ',');
            todaysFruitSupply[i].quantity1 = stof(temp);
            getline(mystream, temp, ',');
            todaysFruitSupply[i].quantity2 = stof(temp);
            getline(mystream, temp, ',');
            todaysFruitSupply[i].quantity3 = stof(temp);
        }

        i++;
        lineCount++;
    }

    myfile.close();

    system("pause");

    return 0;
}
```

EDIT: It was breaking on the last line of the file because there was a new-line character.  After deleting that, it now executes completely.  How can I make sure it can handle that correctly in the future?

Comment: How about making use of heap instead of stack for `todaysFruitSupply `

Comment: @Arunmu except you mean to say "use a `std::vector` instead of an array"?

Comment: Also, use `while (getline(...))` instead of `while(...good..)`

Comment: @crashmstr Yeah, should have been more explicit in my comment

Comment: I'm new to C++.  Not quite comfortable with vectors yet.  Wouldn't a vector fail since the data types are different for each element?  Otherwise I would have used a 2d array.

Comment: If you don't want to use a vector then moving this line `FruitInventory todaysFruitSupply[15000];` above main will solve the blown stack issue.  Once that's fixed, tracing through the code in a debugger would probably help.  It appears the first item in your array won't ever be filled in because you only parse a line when i > 0.  You might rethink that logic a bit since you do have another counter that can tell you when you're on a line you want to parse that isn't tied to the position in the array.

Comment: @eek142 Use `std::vector< FruitInventory > inv; inv.reserve(15000)` and then inside while loop create a single instance of `FruitInventory` on stack (eg: stk_inv), assign the parsed values and push into vector `inv.push_back(stk_inv)`

Comment: @eek142 If that works for you, you may even want to consider using `emplace_back` which would require c++11

Comment: @Retired Ninja moving that declaration out of main solved the immediate crash.  Why though?  I was also able to print some messages and right now it looks like it crashes when it reaches the end of the loop.  Still investigating.

Comment: Global variables aren't allocated on the stack, so you can allocate larger items that way if you need to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a large object to allocate as a local variable:

```
FruitInventory todaysFruitSupply[15000];
```

That's apparently the cause of your stack overflow. As the comment above says, you should consider a dynamic data structure such as a `std::vector` which will grow as needed and manage its memory automatically.

```
std::vector<FruitInventory> todaysFruitSupply;
```

> It was breaking on the last line of the file because there was a new-line character. After deleting that, it now executes completely. How can I make sure it can handle that correctly in the future?

You should check that when you read a line it's not empty:

```
while (myfile.good())
{
    getline(myfile, line);
    if (line.empty())
        break;
```

Or better, don't use keep using `good()` but instead test the result of the input operation:

```
while (getline(myfile, line) && !line.empty())
{
```

The whole thing would look like:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

struct FruitInventory
{
    string date;
    string fruit;
    float quantity1;
    float quantity2;
    float quantity3;
};

int main()
{
    ifstream myfile;
    myfile.open("fruit_inventory.csv", ios::in);

    string line;

    std::vector<FruitInventory> todaysFruitSupply;

    int lineCount = 0;
    getline(myfile, line); // ignore header line

    FruitInventory inv;

    while (getline(myfile, line) && !line.empty())
    {
        stringstream mystream(line);

        string temp;
        getline(mystream, inv.date, ',');
        getline(mystream, inv.fruit, ',');
        getline(mystream, temp, ',');
        inv.quantity1 = stof(temp);
        getline(mystream, temp, ',');
        inv.quantity2 = stof(temp);
        getline(mystream, temp, ',');
        inv.quantity3 = stof(temp);
        if (!mystream)
            break; // something went wrong reading the line

        todaysFruitSupply.push_back(inv);
        lineCount++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Correct for the addendum, of course, and that's why you used the quotation block, but has nothing to do with a "stack overflow" (beyond being posted on one :D).

Comment: I actually added in the !line.empty() check shortly after posting and that fixed the eof error I was having.  Your answer handles skipping the header line very elegantly.  I have a tendency to use good() in the conditional because of how getline() keeps advancing to the next line whenever it is called and that's given me trouble in the past.

I'm new to vectors.  Is there anything atypical about your usage? Can you explain why you didn't insert directly into the vector instead of using push_back()?

Comment: And can you explain why you're breaking for !mystream?  What could cause that to come up if the line is confirmed to not be empty?

Comment: What do you mean "insert directly into the vector"? Using `push_back` inserts directly, to the end of the vector. If the line you read from the file has fewer than the expected number of fields it would cause it to break on `!mystream` (although you'd already have got an exception from `stof` in that case, so maybe it's not needed).

Comment: Why did you have to set values in `inv` instead of `todaysFruitSupply`?  Is that just how vectors work?

Comment: You could insert a "blank" object into the vector and then set values in that object, but it's often cleaner to build an object with the right values then insert it into the vector.

Answer (score -3):

There is no way 15K array of tiny structure can cause stack overflow. Neither removing one empty line from data file will fix it, if there was originally a stack overflow. The problem is different.

```
getline(myfile, line);

//After the above line in your code, you must add:

if ( myfile.eof() ) 
        break;
```

This is because you are checking in while loop if the file is in good status, before reading from it and not after attempt to read from it. Alternatively, you can join the getline (..) && file object health check together:

```
while (getline(myfile, line) && myfile.good() )
```

Both fixes are equivalent (for this problem, though technically they are different) and has no difference at all in the current program and data, but as programmers mature, they will choose the latter. Add a comment below, if this changes work well for you.

Further, you would need to check the presence of non-empty string as well use string tokenizer which will not cause exception. You can use IOException handlers when you learn try/catch.

Comment: Why would this result in a stack overflow?

Comment: First of all, don't be so rude. You are expected to _be nice_ here. Secondly, I see nothing in the OP's code whereby an extra line read will cause a stack overflow. I challenged you to explain why your answer is right, and you failed to provide the goods. The OP didn't remove the empty new line; they moved a declaration into global scope, which is an entirely different thing. So it's a -1 from me.

Comment: The stack overflow is because of the 15k item array being allocated on the stack inside main.  Then it morphed into a different question.

Comment: @RetiredNinja, You mean 150K or 1.5MB will cause stack overflow? The OP uses 1988 PC?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit , Tell me how the code will not cause exception, when getline() is being accessed after .good() and no further check is made before fetch?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit, can you run the OPs code even once in your system, and with my fix and then write? Then I will salute you and agree with you. The OP s problem is different. Mere 1 MB of data (from 15,000 array) cannot cause stack overflow in ANY system.

Comment: @JayKumarR, iostreams don't throw exceptions on error (unless you explicitly tell them to, which the OP's code doesn't do).

Comment: @JonathanWakely, // libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type std::invalid_argument: stof: no conversion
 Read : Abort trap: 6//
This is the exception I got when I run the original code of the OP. Take his unedited original code and run it. Then Apply my fix and run it. You will see that my fix solves his problem. This exception is digression from the main topic.

Comment: The exception tells you where it comes from: stof, not from an iostream read error. Try running `stof("")` and see what happens.